# How can I write this SQL in a better way?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is the query and I'm trying to write it in a better way.

Calculate the average number of languages in every country in a region.

```
CREATE TABLE region3 AS SELECT regions.name, count(country_languages.country_id) FROM regions
RIGHT OUTER JOIN countries on countries.region_id = regions.region_id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN country_languages on countries.country_id = country_languages.country_id
GROUP BY regions.name;

CREATE TABLE region2 AS SELECT regions.name, count(countries.country_id) FROM regions RIGHT OUTER JOIN countries on countries.region_id = regions.region_id GROUP BY regions.name;

SELECT region2.name, region2.count as total_countries, region3.count as langs from region2
LEFT OUTER JOIN region3 on region2.name = region3.name;
SELECT name, ROUND(langs::decimal/total_countries, 1) as avg_lang_count_per_country from regions_new ORDER BY avg_lang_count_per_country DESC;
```

This is how it should look.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong specifically with your current query, what is "better"? What metric are you looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is as simple as:

```
SELECT regions.name, AVG(country_language_count) AS average_country_language_count
FROM regions
JOIN (
    SELECT countries.region_id, COUNT(*) AS country_language_count
    FROM countries
    JOIN country_languages on countries.country_id = country_languages.country_id
    GROUP BY countries.country_id, countries.region_id
) AS subquery1 ON regions.region_id = subquery1.region_id
GROUP BY regions.name
```